# Open Print Dialog with Decoded base64 PDF javascript chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, pdf

I have my PDF coming as base64. I succesfully decode using

```
var decodedData = window.atob(base64String);
```

Now I want to print this data directly without opening an new window. I would prefer to open a print dialog right here and do something like this.

```
//decodedData.printWithDialog or open printer with data.
```

If possible I kindly request a solution that works with Chrome.

Any help would be highly appreciated. Thanks